# What does (+) do in this statement?

Tags: oracle

I would like to understand what is the use of outerjoin in this statement and what difference does it make?

and trunc(sysdate) between effective_start_date(+) and effective_end_date(+)

Comment: Wow... back to the 90s. That syntax was used long time ago when outer joins were not yet standardized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows the join to the table to which those columns belong to remain an outer join (assuming every other reference in the `WHERE` clause to a column from that table is likewise marked), using Oracle's older native syntax. If you remove those `(+)` marks it converts it to an inner join, such that if the join doesn't find a matching row in that outer table, the entire joined row will drop out of the results. The `(+)` keeps such rows from falling out. If no match is found in the outer table, any columns from that table in the `SELECT` clause will be `NULL`, but you don't lose the row. It is equivalent to the ANSI syntax:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN [mytable] ON [join clause] AND trunc(sysdate) between effective_start_date and effective_end_date`

Comment: It depend on the location of the `(+)`. It could also be used to represent a RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @TheImpaler, with native syntax, there really isn't a concept of left vs. right. Position in the `FROM` clause doesn't determine the inner table like it does in ANSI syntax. Logically the inner table becomes whatever tables' join columns are not marked with (+), so conceptually every table that is marked with (+) can be thought of as constituting a left outer join. It's merely academic, I suppose. Who in the world thought up the brilliant idea of there being "left" vs "right"? What's more helpful than "right" or "left" is simply "inner" and "outer" in which case an outer join is an outer join.

Comment: @TheImpaler, (continued) the notion of left vs. right was an unfortunate consequence of ANSI syntax, which gave syntactical meaning to the first named table vs. other joined tables. This is one of the conceptual weaknesses of the ANSI approach. It imposes an arbitrary notion of a primary table when no such primacy may exist in the mind of the programmer or data model, and Oracle's optimizer will frequently follow a very different join order than the syntax suggests.

Comment: Paul, excellent explanation.